# Posted paper css3

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-shapes

I am trying to create a posted paper in pure css3 with transitions and box-shadow.
So far I have accomplished a paper with shadows on both sides but I would like to make it look like this: 
[image]

Is that even possible without images?

```css
.shadow {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
.shadow:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
  -webkit-transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
  transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow">
  edit this even further
</div>
```

Comment: could you post code of what you have tried?

Comment: .shadow:after
{
 right:10px; 
    left:auto;
    -webkit-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg); 
       -moz-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);     
        -ms-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);     
         -o-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg); 
            transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
}

Could paste more... Maximum characters....

Comment: Usually you post code or example code of what your trying to do when you ask questions. I'll edit in what you posted in the comment.
Edit it again to add your own code.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is impossible with CSS but just that it would be way too much effort to create it. I would recommend the usage of SVG because of the bottom left side.

Comment: Seconding @Harry's comment. Not only will it be a pain to create in CSS, you're likely to run into browser incompatibilities that make your desired output look wrong. Use some kind of image or SVG resource.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my attempt, just to give you the idea.

Needs a lot of artistic adjustment, but has all the elements needed.

Included backface-visibility : hidden; thanks to Harry suggestion

```css
.test {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 250px 45px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: rotate(-19deg);
    box-shadow: -9px 10px 31px 6px gray;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.test:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 45px 250px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 50px 180px, rgba(255,255,255,0.3), transparent 70px),
    radial-gradient(circle at 85px 215px, rgba(255,255,255,0.4), transparent 70px),
    radial-gradient(circle at 120px 250px, rgba(255,255,255,0.3), transparent 70px);
    box-shadow: -9px 10px 14px 22px gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Very nice attempt. You could add `backface-visibility: hidden;` to the parent to make the shape even more smoother.